# Animation of a polar circle in python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

Here is my python file to simulate oscillatory dynamics for a circle, which expands and shrinks, permanently:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    r = np.sqrt(np.abs(np.sin(0.1 * i)))
    x = r * np.cos(theta) + 1
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```

But the parametric definition is flawed, such that the result isn't an animated circle, but an ellipsis.

How can I fix the thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')` and also modifying your `ylim` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-1, 1))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    r = np.sqrt(np.abs(np.sin(0.1 * i)))
    x = r * np.cos(theta) + 1
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

This would display it as follows:

[image: equal axis screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

your axes do not have the same length (bounding box), try this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-2, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
    r = 2*np.sqrt(np.abs(np.sin(0.1 * i)))
    x = r * np.cos(theta)
    y = r * np.sin(theta)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

plt.show()
```